# How does aptitude determine what version of a package/application to install?

Tags: linux, apache2

So I wasted several days dealing with a lame Apache2 bug that was fixed in Februry 2012.  I couldn't figure out why I was experiencing the bug still until I discovered my version Apache2 was a 2.2.x version even thought I built up the entire server from scratch Debian 6 on Nov 30, 2012.  For some reason aptitude -install apache2 pulled 2.2.x instead of 2.4.x.

I wish I had known not to assume aptitude will pull the latest stable build.  Can anyone shed some light on how the repositories are managed and why aptitude would be pulling from the older maintained infrastructure instead of the 2.4.x infrastructure?  Also, how would I specifically get aptitude to pull 2.4.x and how can I help myself avoid problems like this in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aptitude` by default takes latest version of the available in your configured repositories in their prioritized order.

But just to illustrate the point, Debian 6 defaults to `apache-2.2`, rather than `apache-2.4`.

```
$ apt-cache showpkg apache
Package: apache
Versions: 

Reverse Depends: 
  apache2.2-common,apache
```